# How to search the minimum positive value in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-in-loop

In my code, `checkTheNextTime()` function's array contains the strings 00.00 to 23.59. By writing this function I want to find the nearest future time. But when I tried with timeTable(shown in code) it returns 23.30 instead of 23.32(Now is 22.24). I guess the compiler search the array right to left. How can I find the nearest future time?

```
var timeTable = ["09.00","10.20","10.35","11.55","12.00","12.40","13.20","14.40","14.50", "23.00", "23.30", "23.31", "23.32"]
func checkTheNextTime(array array: Array<String>) -> String{


    var nextTime: String?
    for index in array {
        let generatedString:String = getTimeAsMinToCheck(finalTime: index)
        let indexInt = Int(generatedString)
        if indexInt > 0{
            nextTime = index
        }

    }

    return nextTime!
}


func getTimeAsMinToCheck(finalTime finalTime: String) -> String{

        let date = NSDate()
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        let now = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale()
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yy HH.mm"
        let datetofinish = formatter.dateFromString("\(now) \(finalTime)")
        let finishDate: NSDate = datetofinish!
        let secondsFromNowToFinish = finishDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
        let minutes = Int(secondsFromNowToFinish / 60)
        return String(minutes)
    }
```

Comment: if `now is 22.24`, shouldn't the `nextTime` be 23.00 from the  `timeTable`???

Comment: It should be 23.00, because 23.00 is the nearest future time with 36 minutes. @Nishant

Comment: is the `timeTable` array sorted?

Comment: It looks like sorted minimum to maximum.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for your requirement:
Done in *Swift 2.0*:

```
    var timeTable = ["09.00","10.20","10.35","11.55","12.00","12.40","13.20","14.40","14.50", "23.00", "23.30", "23.31", "23.32"]

    func checkTheNextTime(array array: Array<String>) -> String{ 

        let currentTime:String = getTimeAsMinToCheck(finalTime: "23.24") // set this value by calculating from current time
        let currentTimeInt = Int(currentTime)// Int value of currentTime

        var nextTime: String? //this will hold the nearest future value

        var minDiff: Int = 24*60 //lets start with maximum value

        for index in timeTable {

            let generatedString:String = getTimeAsMinToCheck(finalTime: index)
            let indexInt = Int(generatedString)

            if (indexInt > currentTimeInt) { //checking for future time only

                let timeDiff = indexInt - currentTimeInt // this will be positive

                if (timeDiff < minDiff) {

                    minDiff = timeDiff //update minDiff as timeDiff is less than minDiff
                    nextTime = index
                }
            }
        }

        return nextTime!
    }
```

Comment: What have you done by using `getTimeAsMinToCheck` function? You can see that func in my edited question. Sorry for missing code. I think you've used it to get time.

Comment: I assumed `getTimeAsMinToCheck` was converting `"23.24"` to `2324`. Have u tried this code?

Comment: I've tried that code and I've noticed that you've used getTimeAsMinToCheck func to get both string and int. In currentTimeInt part you've used it as Int, and generatedString part you've used that as String. Should it return string or int?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 23 is the right answer (its not clear from the comments above), here a a solution using swift 2.0 and closures

1. map your timeTable array into an array of delta's from the current
   time (invalid entries are mapped to 0)
2. add the minimum delta to the time now

---

```
let timeNow: Float = 22.24
let timeTable = ["09.00","10.20","10.35","11.55","12.00","12.40","13.20","14.40","14.50", "23.00", "23.30", "23.31", "23.32"]

let minDelta = timeTable
  .map { Float(NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString($0) ?? 0.0) - timeNow }
  .filter { $0 > 0 }
  .minElement()
let nextTime = (minDelta ?? 0) + timeNow

print(nextTime)  // 23.0
```

Comment: The correct answer is 23.30, because the functions needs to get the minimum future time. These values are clocks.

Comment: Your comment above says for now = 22.24 the answer should be 23.0

Comment: 'It should be 23.00, because 23.00 is the nearest future time with 36 minutes. @Nishant –  twigofa'  ... what does this comment mean then?

Comment: I think in my comment the numbers are a bit confusing. Actually I asked how to find the nearest future time. Anyway I solved it. Thanks

Comment: Glad you solved it but can you clear up the confusion? 22.24 is 10:24pm right?  and 23.0 is 11:00pm,  which is 36 mins later while 23:30 is 11:30pm, which is 66 mins later,  how is 23:30 the "nearer" future time than 23:00?  I guess I am not sure what I am missing and it's a bit disturbing :)